# Why this transaction succeeded to transfer more than its balance?

Tags: erc-20, balances, transferfrom

On BSC chain, [this transaction](https://bscscan.com/vmtrace?txhash=0xb2450e0377e02e6990ab782d17640636468ba44d3ef379cf9be59f139371d3e5&type=gethtrace2) is minting an NFT(MstToken). The evm trace shows it called `MstToken.transferFrom(fromUser, ..., 0x30927f74c9de0000)` to send out 0x30927f74c9de0000 token and it succeeded, the return value is 1:

```json
{
  "type": "CALL",
...
  "calls": [
    {
      "type": "DELEGATECALL",
      ...
      "calls": [
        {
          "type": "CALL", // <-- `transferFrom(user, ..., 0x30927f74c9de0000)`, returns true
          ...
          "input": "0x23b872dd0000000000000000000000009b57b60f14fea2b9889f203ed29db879060147dc000000000000000000000000edc7fd964385ee96b8e2447e2d0e9fd8decad30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030927f74c9de0000",
          "output": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
        },
        {
          "type": "CALL",
```

But when I query the balance of that block from archive node, it shows only 0x13d7adaac0a4940f, less than 0x30927f74c9de0000. My code in Golang:

```go
    client, _ := ethclient.Dial("wss://archive_node_url")

    // token address
    MstAddress := common.HexToAddress("0xe7af3fcc9cb79243f76947402117d98918bd88ea")
    blockNum := big.NewInt(17453505)

    userAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x9b57b60f14fea2b9889f203ed29db879060147dc")

    mst, _ := erc20.NewErc20(MstAddress, client)
    balance, _ := mst.BalanceOf(&bind.CallOpts{
        BlockNumber: blockNum,
    }, userAddress)

    fmt.Println(balance)
```

I thought maybe the user send two transactions at same block, first sending some token to it and then mints. But I check on that block number, there seems only one tx from the user.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're querying the block that transaction was executed on, so you'll get the amount *after* state change.

If you want to check the previous state, query block 17453504.